# How to fetch specific data from same class div using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a link : https://www.cagematch.net/?id=2&nr=448&gimmick=Adam+Pearce

In this link there data in divs with same class name. But I want to fetch specifi div. Like I want to fetch current gimmik then age and brand nothing else. I tried this code :

```
url = "http://www.cagematch.net/?id=8&nr=1&page=15"
headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "deflate"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

links = [
    "https://www.cagematch.net/" + a["href"] for a in soup.select(".TCol a")
]
list = []
for u in links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(u, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )
    # print(soup.h1.text)
    with open("wwe/maw.csv", 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f:
        wrt = writer(f)
        for info in soup.select_all(".InformationBoxRow"):
            # header1 = info.select_one(".InformationBoxTitle").text
            # header2 = info.select_one(".InformationBoxContents").text
            # table = [header1, header2, "/"]

            header1 = info.select("div", class_="InformationBoxContents").text
            print(header1)
```

With this I am getting all the data from that page. But I want to fetch only some of them. How can I get that. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "deflate"}


def get_info(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )

    title = soup.h1.text.strip()
    gimmick = soup.select_one(
        '.InformationBoxTitle:-soup-contains("Current gimmick") + div'
    ).text.strip()
    age = soup.select_one(
        '.InformationBoxTitle:-soup-contains("Age") + div'
    ).text.strip()

    return {"Name": title, "Gimmick": gimmick, "Age": age}


data = []
urls = ["https://www.cagematch.net/?id=2&nr=448&gimmick=Adam+Pearce"]
for url in urls:
    data.append(get_info(url))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Name      Gimmick       Age
0  Adam Pearce  Adam Pearce  44 years
```

Comment: Can you add code for all the wrestlers? It will be useful for me. Actually I am learning. If possible please post the answer for all the wrestlers just like you showed them. @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @Sukuna That I leave to you, just combine the previous and this answer (hint - put the function `get_info()` into a for loop and create final dataframe.)

Comment: Yes I did it. Thanks a lot @Andrej Kesely

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as part of the code:

```py
    result=get(url='https://www.cagematch.net/?id=2&nr=448&gimmick=Adam+Pearce') 
    src=result.content 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml') 
    result = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"InformationBoxContents"}) 
    print(result)
```

Comment: Please improve your answer and add some context to clarify. Thanks

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.